# Pathfinder Equivalent of Infinite Scrollcase?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eberron, magic-items

Is there an equivalent of the Infinite Scrollcase from *Magic of Eberron* in Pathfinder.  In particular I'm looking for an item that stores multiple scrolls and allows a caster to more easily access the desired scroll?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a *handy* substitution.

[Bag, Handy Haversack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack) can store much more than [Infinite Scrollcase](http://dndtools.eu/items/magic-item-compendium--73/infinite-scrollcase--416/)'s 50 scrolls, gets the scroll out as the same *move action*, does not provoke an AoO either in doing so and is priced at 2000 gp vs 2800 gp.

If you feel fancy, you can retrieve the scroll in question with the help of an [Unseen Servant](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/unseenServant.html).

As an added benefit, you can store anything you like there.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't allow the nifty "draw a scroll while moving" ability as the Infinite Scrollcase, but it's probably a good balance.

Comment: One could argue that ordering an _unseen servant_ to draw a scroll may be done while moving, but that's an uncharted homerule territory.

Comment: And not much help for an Oracle.

Comment: Why not use the Efficient Quiver http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/efficient-quiver

Answer (score 2):

### Why not just use the Infinite Scrollcase from the Magic Items Compendium?

The infinite scrollcase that you mentioned has an item entry in a 3.5 handbook, The Magic Items compendium that is cross-compatible with pathfinder content. The entry in the MiC reads the following:

### Infinite Scrollcase

```
Price: 2,800 gp
Item Level: 7th
Body Slot: held
Caster Level: 9th
Aura: Moderate; (DC 19) Conjuration
Activation: Move (manipulation)
Weight: 3.0 lb.
```

This elaborate mahogany tube has a slit that runs along its length. A wooden dowel, capped on the ends with gold, fi ts against the slit, locking into place with jeweled clasps.

An infinite scrollcase holds up to fifty scrolls or other parchments, which can be placed within it or removed as with any normal scrollcase. When you activate an infinite scrollcase, the desired scroll unfurls through
the slit, ready to read or cast from. When you cast a spell from a scroll unfurled from an infinite scrollcase, you gain a +4 competence bonus on Concentration checks made to cast that spell defensively.

If you have at least a +1 base attack bonus, you can retrieve a scroll from an infinite scrollcase as part of a move action, similar to drawing a weapon.

Prerequisites: Craft Wondrous Item , Leomund's Secret Chest .

Cost to Create: 1,400 gp, 112 XP, 3 day(s).

---

Since Pathfinder was crafted from using 3.5 as a base system the items in the source books can easily be ported over and used in Pathfinder, pending GM approval of course. Ask your GM if it's okay, and show him the Pathfinder equivalent. ( Hayward's Handy Haversack )